# Add video files to asset library using PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

I want to add video files to the Asset Library programmatically using powershell and 
Kindly help me. I tried the below code :

```
 Add-PSSnapIn Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
 $sitecollecURL ="http://sirvr1:123/sites/enggtest"
 $videoFolderPath = "C:\Myvideofolder\"
 $videoLibFiles = Get-ChildItem $videoFolderPath -Include      
 *.wmv,*.mp3,*.mp4,*.flv,*.avi -Recurse 
 Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "starting to add video  item to the asset  
 library " $sitecollecURL
 $siteDiscipline = Get-SPSite $sitecollecURL
```

My idea is to get the different video or audio files kept in the  folder and read one by one which matches the extension and upload into the assets library

Answer (score 0):

Your collection of files will be now stored in the below variable

```
 $videoLibFiles = Get-ChildItem $videoFolderPath -Include *.wmv,*.mp3,*.mp4,*.flv,*.avi -Recurse
```

Now loop through the variable $videoLibFiles to get the full file path and provide it as an input to uploading files to library

```
    foreach($filepath in $videoLibFiles)
{
$filepath.FullName
//Code to upload files

}
```

Please use this link to add files to assets library :
[Add file to library](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19529.sharepoint-2010-upload-file-in-document-library-using-powershell.aspx)

Comment: Mark it as answer if you find it as the solution. Thanks.

Comment: i got an error like  given below:Exception calling "GetFile" with "1" argument(s): "Value does not fall within the expected range."
At C:\videoScripts\AddVideostoDocLibwithConfirmation.ps1:36 char:5
+     [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFile]$spFile = $spWeb.GetFile("/" + $folder.Url + "/ ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentException

Comment: when i am trying to run this linje of code it gave me error                                                           [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFile]$spFile  =                   $folder.Files.Add($folder.Url + "/" + $File.Name, [System

Comment: Can you share your script so that it will be easier to identify the issue ?

Comment: Start-SPAssignment -Global  $webUrl  = "http://sRVR1:123/sites/ENGGtest"
    $FilePath ="C:\Maddy\Scripts\Wildlife.wmv"    $spWeb = Get-SPWeb -Identity $webUrl $spWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = $true;            $List = $spWeb.Lists["VideoLib"]        
$folder = $List.RootFolder $FileName = $FilePath.Substring($FilePath.LastIndexOf("\")+1) $File= Get-ChildItem $FilePath  Write-Host $File    [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFile]$spFile = $spWeb.GetFile("/" + $folder.Url + "/" + $File.Name)

Comment: $flagConfirm = 'y' if($spFile.Exists -eq $true)  { $flagConfirm = Read-Host "File $FileName already exists in library $DocLibName, do you    want to upload a new version(y/n)?" }  if ($flagConfirm -eq 'y' -or $flagConfirm -eq 'Y') Write-Host "yes, file is already in  videoib" $fileStream = ([System.IO.FileInfo] (Get-Item $File.FullName)).OpenRead()

Comment: am sorry, i dont know, how to add this code.it has soem 1000+ chars which stackexchange doesnt allow to paste it here. is there any way io can paste the entire code here

Comment: Can you use this line of script instead of the one existing to fetch the file? [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFile]$spFile=$spWeb.GetFile( "/" + $File.Name)